# C: TCP server doesnt receive the whole message

Tags: c, tcp, server, null, client

Hello everyone im trying to make a server which will receive a message like :"str1\0str2\0str3\0" and then separate in substrings. On the client side everything seems to work fine but when im receiving the message on the server side i receive only "str1". Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Server:

```
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read( newsockfd,buffer, 255 );

   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);


   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++){
       printf("%c", buffer[i],i);
       if ( buffer[i] == 0 ){
       printf("0");
     }
   }`
```

Client:

```
   char buffer[256];
   int length =0;
   char *uptr = buffer;
   int i;

       strcpy(uptr,argv[3]);
       length = length + strlen(argv[3])-3;

       for ( i = 4 ; i < argc  ; i++){

          memcpy(uptr+length+i, argv[i]  ,strlen(argv[i]) +1);

          length = length + strlen(argv[i]);

       }

       buffer[length + (argc - 1)]= 0;


       for(i = 0; i < length + argc; i++){
           printf("%c", buffer[i],i);

       }
```

Comment: How do you know that you only receive "str1"?   What do you get if you printf out 'n'?

Comment: `\0` marks the end of a string in C, it's possible that you received all the data but the print function assumes the string has ended.

Comment: .. besides, it's quite possible, (though unlikely). that you only get 's' the first time, due to the octet-streaming nature of TCP.

Comment: You are doing strange things with your `uptr`and `length`. In `memcpy(` you are adding the current loop counter to your destination address. After the loop you cut your string at length plus argument count. You copy argv[3] but add strlen(argv[3])-3? Whats about argv[1] and [2]. There is not test whether argv[3] is available.

Comment: `for( ; i < strlen(buffer); )` This will stop at the first \0 regardless how many bytes you received. `printf("%c", buffer[i],i);` This is mismatch in format string and parameters. Your client does not send anything.

Answer (score 0):

You never wrote any code to receive a message. So it's not surprising that your code doesn't receive a message.

```
  bzero(buffer,256);
  n = read( newsockfd,buffer, 255 );
```

This reads some data that might or might not be a message. After all, the `read` function has no idea what your messages are like.

```
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

Wait, what? What makes this a message? This is just some bytes you read from the connection. It's not a message.

You need to write some code to receive a message, otherwise you won't receive messages but just a bunch of bytes from the connection.